# PHP Function to devide an array of N elements in N sub array

Tags: php, arrays

Let say I have an array of N elements. I want to divide it as much as possible equally into M sub arrays to make M columns.

Do you know how I could do that in PHP ?
I've tried [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Here is two example :

```
$array = range(1, 10);
$number_of_split = 3;
```

The array should be split into 3 sub arrays of 4 elements for the first sub array and 3 elements for the two other sub arrays.

```
$array = range(1, 27);
$number_of_split = 5;
```

The array should be split into 5 sub arrays of 6 elements for the two first sub arrays and 5 elements for the three other sub arrays.

Comment: What have you tried? And how is `array_chunk()` different from what you want? Please post an expected output as well

Comment: Your definition of splitting seems weird. Please define it more clearly. Perhaps then you might find the algorithm you need ;) There's no built-in function for this, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: I think he wants to split AND balance, so that you dont get an array of size 5, 5 and 1, but 4, 4 and 3

Comment: @TheShiftExchange that's what I want to do. My examples seem pretty clear. I don't understand why I get vote down for my question...

Comment: @user12073 You (probably) get vote down because you showed no effort, no code of yourself that already tries to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function from [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php#75022).

```
function partition($list, $p) {
    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for($px = 0; $px < $p; $px ++) {
        $incr = ($px < $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$array = array();
$array = range(1, 10);
$number_of_split = 3;
$chunks = partition($array, $number_of_split);
print_r($chunks);
```