# Create balanced groups using for loop and ceil

Tags: php

Using the following code I can create 3 groups in a loop -

```
$groupSize = ceil($number_students/3);
$j=1; 
for($i=1;$i<$number_students;$i++){
    if($i%$groupSize == 1){
        if($i!=0){
            echo '</fieldset>';
        }
        echo '<fieldset><legend>Group #'.$j.'</legend>';
        $j++;
    }
    echo '<div>Student #'.$i.'</div>';
}
echo '</fieldset>';
```

if `$number_students = 7` the result is

```
Group #1
    Student #1
    Student #2
    Student #3
Group #2
    Student #4
    Student #5
    Student #6
Group #3
    Student #7
```

How could I modify the loop so that it balances each group, ie.

```
Group #1
    Student #1
    Student #2
    Student #3
Group #2
    Student #4
    Student #5
Group #3
    Student #6
    Student #7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using modulo with floating point values ([fmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php)) instead will give you this functionality.
Everytime we encounter a remainder that is less than 1, we create a new group. Please observe that I've changed the base of `$i` to 0 for a better fit with modulo calculations.

```
$numberStudents = 7;
$groupCount = 3;
$groupSize = $numberStudents/$groupCount;                // Will be 2.333..
$j=1;
for($i=0;$i<$numberStudents;$i++){
    if(fmod($i,$groupSize) < 1){
        if($i!=0){
            echo '</fieldset>';
        }
        echo '<fieldset><legend>Group #'.$j.'</legend>';
        $j++;
    }
    echo '<div>Student #'.($i+1).'</div>';
}
echo '</fieldset>';
```

The remainders should in order become:

```
> $i 0    remainder 0                (New Group 1)
> $i 1    remainder 1
> $i 2    remainder 2
> $i 3    remainder 0.66666666666667 (New Group 2)
> $i 4    remainder 1.66666666666667
> $i 5    remainder 0.33333333333333 (New Group 3)
> $i 6    remainder 1.33333333333333
```

Effectively giving a result of 3,2,2 students in the groups for this example.
Changing the numbers to something like 17 students in 5 groups will also work nicely, be aware that in such a scenario generate groups would be 4,3,4,3,3 instead, so the larger groups may not always end up as the first ones.

Comment: Brilliant! Was not aware of [`fmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php). This is what I was looking to find.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24634011/689579) from [PHP Function to devide an array of N elements in N sub array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633776/php-function-to-devide-an-array-of-n-elements-in-n-sub-array), I was able to solve it by 1st splitting them into balanced groups before I loop to display the groups.

```
function partition($list, $p) {
    $listlen = count($list);
    $partlen = floor($listlen / $p);
    $partrem = $listlen % $p;
    $partition = array();
    $mark = 0;
    for($px = 1; $px <= $p; $px ++) {
        $incr = ($px <= $partrem) ? $partlen + 1 : $partlen;
        $partition[$px] = array_slice($list, $mark, $incr);
        $mark += $incr;
    }
    return $partition;
} 

$number_students = 7;

$array = range(1, $number_students);
$number_of_split = 3;
$group = partition($array, $number_of_split);

foreach($group as $key => $students){
  echo '<fieldset><legend>Group #'.$key.'</legend>';
    foreach($students as $studentNum){
        echo '<div>Student #'.$studentNum.'</div>';
    }
echo '</fieldset>';
}
```